# Conditional not working when all looks fine

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

Good day, I have a script in my Unity game, it creates a list and it randomize its numbers order, then, the value passes to another list to check some specific properties, this is the code:

```
// Use this for initialization
private List<int> PreList = new List<int>();
private List<int> ButtonList = new List<int>();
private List<int> UserList = new List<int>();
private System.Random Rnd = new System.Random();

void Randomizer()
{
    PreList.Add(1);
    PreList.Add(2);
    PreList.Add(3);
    PreList.Add(4);
    PreList.Add(5);
    PreList.Add(6);
    PreList.Add(7);
    PreList.Add(8);
    PreList.Add(9);
    PreList = PreList.OrderBy(C => Rnd.Next()).ToList();
    foreach (int Number in PreList)
    { 
        Debug.Log(Number);
        Debug.Log(ButtonList.Count);
        if (Number == 1)
        {
            OneMethod();
        }
        else if (Number == 2)

        {
            TwoMethod();
        }
        else if (Number == 3)

        {
            ThreeMethod();
        }
        else if (Number == 4)

        {
            FourMethod();
        }
        else if (Number == 5)

        {
            FiveMethod();
        }
        else if (Number == 6)

        {
            SixMethod();
        }
        else if (Number == 7)

        {
            SevenMethod();
        }
        else if (Number == 8)

        {
            EightMethod();
        }
        else if (Number == 9)

        {
            NineMethod();
        }
    }
}
    void OneMethod()
    {
        ButtonList.Add(1);
        GameObject RedButton = GameObject.Find("Red"); 
//There are 8 methods just like this, but it variates some stuff like the name and the number, all of these add numbers to ButtonList
    }
```

At this moment, the output console just says that the count of the ButtonList is 9, but, if i put an if to check that, it never gets the value to true, is like it doesnt execute the methods and the ifs never runs, but, do you have any idea of why?

Comment: Can you show the full console output?

Comment: Step through code using F11 and see what happens.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? I just ran your code as a C# console application and it is working fine. It creates a list of values from 1-9, randomizes them, and then enters an if statement based on the value.  Where are you putting the if statement to check the Count of your `buttonList`?

Comment: WHEN do you do the "if check"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but here's a better way of generating random-order lists:

```
public class MyClass {
    private List<int> PreList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    private List<int> ButtonList = new List<int>();
    private List<int> UserList = new List<int>();

    void Randomizer() {
        while (PreList.Count > 0 ) {
            var idx = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, PreList.Count); // Randomly select from remaining items
            var value = PreList[idx]; // Get item value
            PreList.RemoveAt(idx); // Remove item from future options
            ButtonList.Add(value); // Add to end of 'randomised' list
        }

        foreach (var value in ButtonList) {
            DoSomethingWith(value);
        }
    }

    void DoSomethingWith(int value) {
        switch(value) {
            case 1: OneMethod(); break;
            case 2: TwoMethod(); break;
            case 3: ThreeMethod(); break;
            case 4: FourMethod(); break;
            case 5: FiveMethod(); break;
            case 6: SixMethod(); break;
            case 7: SevenMethod(); break;
            case 8: EightMethod(); break;
            case 9: NineMethod(); break;
        }
    }
}
```

*Edit: Added example use of `DoSomething()`*

Comment: But the problem here is that I need to execute the methods, so it highlights in an order, do you know what iMimic is? Just exactly like that

Comment: @PazlGame I added some code to call your functions. (Just remove the `ButtonList.Add()` from your functions).  This code does exactly the same thing as your OP.